# How to remove broken linked layers from ArcMap in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, layers

In Python there is a function to list all broken data sources in a MapDocument:

```
brknList = arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd)
```

You could then use this function to remove such broken links:

```
arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
```

How can I do a similar operation in ArcObjects 10.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ILayer2` interface has a property *Valid* which can be used to test if a layer is broken.

The equivalent ArcObjects code to remove a layer from the Map is `IMap.DeleteLayer`. Note the remarks in the API help about `IDataLayer2.Disconnect`.